# "Attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Tags: python, django

When i want to save this django file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views  

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='main-view')
]
```

I get an error :

"ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

What should I do with it?

Comment: `import views`?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an `__init__.py` file in the same directory as your file. Then add `import views` in that `__init__.py` file.

It should work but if it doesn't then try adding the following snippet in your code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
```

**EDIT**: This snippet should be at the top of the file, before other imports.