# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package STILL NO SOLUTION

Tags: python

I have looked at I think 5 different answers to this problem, yet none of them have worked for me yet. For reference, I've looked through all of these posts:

[Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

[Attempted relative import with no known parent package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084977/attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package)

["Attempted relative import with no known parent package"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894432/attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package)

From what I've gathered, there are two solutions to this problem:

1. Move the `.py` file you're trying to import functions from into the same directory as the script you're trying to run (this works, but it is not a good solution, I should be able to import from a parent directory without this error)
2. Create a `__init__.py` file in the directory of the `.py` file you're trying to import from, and use `import package_name` to it. (I have tried this, but same issue)

Here is my project's structure:

[image: structure]

I'm trying to run the `test.py` script, which (attempts) to import the function `add_technical_indicators` from the `add_technical_indicators.py` file. My import statement looks like this:

`from ..utils.add_technical_indicators import add_technical_indicators`

Looking at the folder structure again, I have to go UP one directory, then into the `utils` folder to bring in the `add_technical_indicators` .py file, and finally the function `add_technical_indicators`.

Here's what I have tried so far:

`from ..utils.add_technical_indicators import add_technical_indicators`

`from .utils.add_technical_indicators import add_technical_indicators`

`from utils.add_technical_indicators import add_technical_indicators` (this doesn't work of course because `add_technical_indicators` is not in the same folder as the script being run)

Created an `__init__.py` file in the `utils` folder that reads `import add_technical_indicators`

Created an `__init__.py` file in the `misc` folder that reads `import test`

None of it works. I need a concise and actionable answer as to why this is still not working. I'm running Python 3.7.9, Windows 10, and VS code in case that matters.

I have looked through previous, repeat answers but none of them have worked for me, so although this IS a duplicate question, please do not close it until I have a solution because linking to the already "answered" questions didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### short solution

In `test.py` import as `from utils.add_technical_indicators import add_technical_indicators`
and run as `python -m misc.test` (not `test.py`) in parent directory(in `STOCK_PEAKS_ADN_THROUGHS_2`)

#### explained

python cannot import files from upper directory of your working directory unless you add them to `PATH`, so `from ..utils.add_technical_indicators import add_technical_indicators` won't work.

python finds files starting from your working directory, so `from utils.add_technical_indicators import add_technical_indicators` in `test.py` can find `utils/add_technical_indicators.py` **if you run script at parent directory.**

`python -m misc.test` will run misc/test.py in parent directory. Note that `python misc/test.py` will run script in `misc` directory and will give you same error.

Comment: Thank you! I see what I was doing wrong, can't look up a directory if I'm running the project from inside a sub dir. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You did the right thing here: `from ..utils.add_technical_indicators import add_technical_indicators`

The main issue must be in the imports of utils/add_technical_indicators.py file

Did you try importing stuffs inside add_technical_indicators.py relative to itself (if so, those imports only work when add_technical_indicators.py is run instead of test.py)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMPNW.png)

write this for above structure

from quotetutorial.quotetutorial.items import QuotetutorialItem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).