# import with no known parent package

Tags: python

I found similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62894432/attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package).
But my problem is it works running python code in normal mode.
When I run in debugging as python -m pdb nmt.py, I have `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. My python version is Python 3.7.13.
Error is coming from the following line.

```
from . import inference
```

How to make it work in debugging?

Comment: Replace `from . import inference` with `import inference`

Comment: Can you show us your folder structure? The `-m` flag runs it as a module, which has a slightly different way of working than a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanations

The error message is actually pretty explicit:

Relatives import (using `from . import module`, or `from .module import something`) Only work if the module (ie the file) you are editing, and the module you are importing are in the same python [package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

That means you need a `__init__.py` file in that directory (for it to be considered a package).

I recommend you read [the documentation on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) if you want to understand the import system better

### Quick fixes

- either add a `__init__.py` to make your directory into a package
- or change your relative import to a normal import (ie. change `from . import inference` to `import inference`.)  — you may need to add the directory containing your files to `sys.path` [(documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)

Comment: I have __init__.py in folder. I can run with no error when I use `python -m nmt.nmt --src=vi --tgt=en`. But I have that when I run `python -m pdb nmt/nmt.py --src=vi --tgt=en`. What is the difference?

Comment: oh the command you use is wrong. It should be `python -m pdb -m nmt.nmt`

Comment: Just think of it as "`python -m pdb` replaces `python`" in your command

Comment: Yes that is the one `python -m pdb -m nmt.nmt`

Comment: the difference is that `-m` runs your module as a module, whether the other one runs it as a standalone script